# Login With LinkedIn in Xamarin.Forms : Error Authenticating: Invalid_request Exception?

Tags: xamarin.forms, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

I am implementing linkedin login with xamarin.auth. Please see screenshot for exception. I tried to put breakpoints but they are not hit and exception arises. Help me solve this please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this is perhaps not the best solution but at least no more annoying alert.

Just before you do your call( var request = xxxx ) 
Add the following line:

> auth.ShowErrors = false;

No more popup :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was the Redirect URL. Used this one instead and it worked: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth-success. You need to dismiss the Auth UI in the Completed callback.